# Giving Potential Memory Leak warning and app crashes

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks

I am doing video recording using `ScreenCaptureView.`

I have used following code ;

```
 -(CGContextRef) createBitmapContextOfSize:(CGSize) size

    {    CGContextRef    context = NULL;     CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;     int             bitmapByteCount;

        int bitmapBytesPerRow;

        bitmapBytesPerRow   = (size.width * 4);      
        bitmapByteCount     = (bitmapBytesPerRow * size.height); 
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
         if (bitmapData != NULL)
         {       
            free(bitmapData);   
         }

         bitmapData = malloc( bitmapByteCount );
          if (bitmapData == NULL)
         {      
               fprintf (stderr, "Memory not allocated!");   
               return context=NULL;      
         }    

    context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData, size.width, size.height, 8, bitmapBytesPerRow,colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);

    CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context,NO);
        if (context== NULL)
         {
        free (bitmapData);
        fprintf (stderr, "Context not created!");
        return NULL;
    }

    return context;

    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
}
```

But it gives me Potential Memory Leak warning and app crashes.

It works fine in ipod but gets crash in ipad.

How can i solve it ?

Thanks......

Comment: @Maulik - thanks for editing. Please give answer for the question too...!!! Mogs.. :-)

Comment: have u tried with @autoreleasepool?

Comment: @Ganapathy - no i have not tried autoreleaseool. How to use it?

Comment: what is this bitmapdata?

Comment: @user2135853: wow.. whats your crash log ?

Comment: @Maulik - It gives log message as - "*** -[CALayer release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x3493b0"

Comment: @user2135853 what is the bitmapdata? what type?

Comment: @LithuT.V - It is "bitmapData = malloc( bitmapByteCount );"

Answer (score 1):

```
CGContextRelease(context);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
```

Should be placed before

```
return context;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But it is crashing.

Comment: this is wrong i think.if you release context before returning .What will be returned?

Comment: Yeah, I guess some sort of autoreleasepool should be used.

Answer (score 0):

CGContextRef internally contains some memory allocation. so just try once with @autoreleasepool like this.

```
         -(CGContextRef) createBitmapContextOfSize:(CGSize) size

            {   
  @autoreleasepool
   {

             CGContextRef    context = NULL;     
               CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;     
                  int bitmapByteCount;

                int bitmapBytesPerRow;

                bitmapBytesPerRow   = (size.width * 4);      
                bitmapByteCount     = (bitmapBytesPerRow * size.height); 
                colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
                 if (bitmapData != NULL)
                 {       
                    free(bitmapData);   
                 }

                 bitmapData = malloc( bitmapByteCount );
                  if (bitmapData == NULL)
                 {      
                       fprintf (stderr, "Memory not allocated!");   
                       return context=NULL;      
                 }    

            context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData, size.width, size.height, 8, bitmapBytesPerRow,colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);

            CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context,NO);
                if (context== NULL)
                 {
                free (bitmapData);
                fprintf (stderr, "Context not created!");
                return NULL;
            }
            return context;

            CGContextRelease(context);
            CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
  }

        }
```

Comment: thanks again for reply. but it is still crashing and gives messave as "*** -[CALayer release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x3493b0"